# Benefits of where notation in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, scope, where-clause

What are the pros and cons of explicit function definition as opposed to where notation in Haskell?

Explicit function definition:

```
foo :: Integer -> Integer
foo a = bar a
  where
    bar :: Integer -> Integer
    bar a = Some code here
```

as opposed to:

```
foo :: Integer -> Integer
foo a = bar a

bar :: Integer -> Integer
bar a = Some code here
```

Why would I use one over the other? Is there anything to be aware of with regards to efficiency? Security? Code reusability? Code readability?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your auxiliary function is not going to be used anywhere else, it's better not to pollute the namespace and use a local definition.

When your outer function has only one top-level "pattern", the `where` clause can simplify the definition of the auxiliary function because the parameters of the outer function will be in scope.

```
outer x v z f = undefined
    where 
        inner i = i + x + v + z + f
```

versus

```
outer x v z f = undefined

inner x v z f i = i + x + v + z + f
```

If your function has more than one top-level "pattern", then you can't share bindings across patters using `where`. You have to define a top-level binding.

Certain ways of using `where` can incur in non-obvious performance penalties. This definition (taken from the HaskellWiki article on [let vs where](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Let_vs._Where))

```
fib x = map fib' [0 ..] !! x
    where
      fib' 0 = 0
      fib' 1 = 1
      fib' n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
```

is slower than this one:

```
fib = (map fib' [0 ..] !!)
    where
      fib' 0 = 0
      fib' 1 = 1
      fib' n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
```

and also slower than defining `fib'` at the top-level.

The reason is that, in the first definition, a new `fib'` is created for each invocation of `fib`. Explained [here](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-October/084538.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you need bar only in the scope of foo, it is more readable and better information hiding to declare it in "where". If bar should be reusable outside of foo, the it needs to be declared parallel to foo.

Comment: This is not exactly an answer.